# How to append multiple strings from a single input into a list in Python

Tags: python, string, list, append

I'm writting a program where the user has to input some random words like this:

*Enter some words: apple, house, fire, guitar*

and then I have to take this individual words (without the commas) and place them in a list. How do I take an input with several words and put them in a list?

Comment: youvar.split(',')

Comment: add replace(' ', '') to remove whitespaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `.split(',')` which returns list separated by `,`:

```
inp = input('Enter some words: ')
my_list = inp.split(',')
print(my_list)
```

Result:

```
Enter some words: apple, house, fire, guitar
['apple', ' house', ' fire', ' guitar']
```

Or, following would give same results too:

```
input_list = input('Enter some words: ').split(',')
print(input_list)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: Great! `Happy Coding`.